# Magento custom price on Quote Item is ignored?

Tags: magento

I want to be able to change price on Quote Items to be different than on Products, based on several Tutorials I have used this code:

```
$quoteItem->setCustomPrice($price);
$quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
$quoteItem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
$quote->save();
```

After that when I get to cart it shows normal prices, not custom price. I have checked Quote Items in cart and they have correct customPrice, but it seems to be ignored. Do I have to activate something else to make this custom prices to take effect?

PS:

Magento v1.7

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, so I found the problem, somehow it didnt get saved in my script. Not sure why, but I have rewritten my code into 2 functions, 1 for adding product, the other for changing price.

So this code is all that is necessary:

```
$quoteItem->setCustomPrice($price);
$quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
$quoteItem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
$quoteItem->save();
```

No need to save quote, just quoteItem.

Comment: Can you share how you are changing the price. I am facing same issue,

Comment: Hi, I am sorry, but I have not worked with Magento for a long time. Therefore I am not sure now how to do it.

Comment: It's ok I am trying myself.

Answer (score 2):

Should be an easy fix: If I'm not mistaken you are trying to save the price of a quote item, but you save the quote instead. You need to save the quote item itself as well.

```
$quoteItem->setCustomPrice($price);
$quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
$quoteItem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
$quoteItem->save();
$quote->save();
```

Comment: Tried that too, but it is not necessary to save quoteitem. When I get to cart the items do have those custom prices saved.